# Rendering RSS feed (XML) in React with jquery, why do object values parsed from the feed seem empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, reactjs, rss

I'm trying to render the title from an item parsed from the feed just for a test. It always either gives me an error message telling me that the title is undefined or null (tried multiple small modifications to the code). However, the getNews() method seems to set 30 objects to the state as it is supposed to. I am just unable to render any values from them. Can anyone see what is wrong with my approach? Is there something wrong with the query?

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = { news: [] }; 
        this.getNews = this.getNews.bind(this); 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getNews();
    }

    getNews() {

        $.get("https://www.hs.fi/rss/tuoreimmat.xml",function(data) {    

            var $xml = $(data);   
            var items = [];

            $xml.find("item").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    item = {
                        title: $this.find("title").text(),
                        link: $this.find("link").text(),
                        description: $this.find("description").text(),
                        pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                    }

                items.push(item);

            }.bind(this));   

            this.setState({ news: items });

        }.bind(this)); 
    }

    render() { 

        var newsItem = this.state.news[1]; 
        var title = newsItem.title;

        return (
            <div className="App">
              <header className="App-header">
                <h1 className="App-title">News</h1>
              </header>
              <div className="App-feeds">
              </div>
              <div className="panel-list">{title}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how the ajax call and the rendering works. When you execute the program, React tries to render the component directly, so the ajax get call hasn't been completed and the state variable is still empty. Once you receive your response, you update the state with all your news and React update the view. But when it starts, in the render you try to access `this.state.news[1]`, but `this.state.news` is still an empty empty, so you get the `undefined`.

A little patch just to allow you to check it is to initialize the state with...

```
this.state = { news: [{},{}] };
```

... so now `this.state.news[1]` exists and you'll see how is refreshed when the ajax call is completed.

I suppose the final purpose is to show all titles, or all news, etc. So you want have that problem, because in the render you'll have to "loop" through all the values of `this.state.news` (with the `map` function, I guess), and when is empty it won't fail.

Here you have your code modified with the patch to see it working. Have it a look because I've tried to clean it a little bit...

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = { news: [{},{}] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getNews();
    }

    getNews() {

        $.get("https://www.hs.fi/rss/tuoreimmat.xml",function(data) {    

            var $xml = $(data);   
            var items = [];

            $xml.find("item").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                items.push({
                    title: $this.find("title").text(),
                    link: $this.find("link").text(),
                    description: $this.find("description").text(),
                    pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                });
            });

            this.setState({ news: items });

        }.bind(this),'xml');    
    }

    render() { 
        return (
            <div className="App">
              <header className="App-header">
                <h1 className="App-title">News</h1>
              </header>
              <div className="App-feeds">
              </div>
              <div className="panel-list">{this.state.news[1].title}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the corresponding fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/x1ty26bq/

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the problem so thoroughly! I was really struggling to find where the root of my problem was and how to fix it.

Comment: My pleasure! Have a nice day and happy coding!